# Hover transitional delay with sequential message

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to achieve is a fake loading message as the user hovers over the div before it shows the actual div content.

```
.info {  opacity: 0; width: 200px; height: 300px;transition-duration: 0.3s; transition-delay: 2s;  margin-top: -20px; background-color: #000;}

.info:hover { opacity: 1; transition-duration: 0.3s; transition-delay: 2s; }

.access {opacity: 0.0;  transition-duration: 0.3s; transition-delay: 0.5s; background-color: #000; color: #fff}
.access:hover { opacity: 1;  transition-duration: 0.3s; transition-delay: 0.5s;  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/499hM/

As you can see, the message appears and then the div but the message reappears over the top of the div and fades it out - I want the message to disappear once the div has "loaded". I'm hoping this can be achieved through CSS alone?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure that this is something you want to do with a transition. It's more suited to an animation or Js/JQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you canuse the adjacent selector and set 2 transitions on 2 different child of your boxe.

the `.loading` message first in flow, once hovered shows up and the next child (`+ .infos`) will show up on top of it a little while after. from there, the `.infos` takes over the `:hover` to keep on top.

DEMO:

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/jilLp

```
<div>
  <p class="loading">
    loading ...
  </p>
  <p class="infos">
    Infos
  </p>
</div>
```

```
div {
  border:solid;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:gray solid 5px;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
}
.loading , .infos{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  line-height:200px;
  background:black;
  color:white;
  z-index:5;
  opacity:0;
}
.infos {
  z-index:0;
  background:yellow;
  line-height:1.2em;;
  color:red;
}
.loading:hover {
  opacity:1;
}
.loading:hover + .infos, .infos:hover {
  opacity:1;
  transition:2s 1s;
  z-index:10;
}
```